# Mandatory OPC-UA services

Tags: opc-ua, node-opcua

Can anyone tell me the OPC-UA document in which I could find all the mandatory services provided by OPC-UA?

Thank You in Advance!

With Regards,

Avdoot Chalke

Answer (score 2):

OPC UA Specification, Part 7: Profiles

https://opcfoundation.org/developer-tools/specifications-unified-architecture/part-7-profiles/

Answer (score 1):

It might be not easy to figure out that reading specs. 
There is online tool which is useful to figure out what is mandatory and what is optional for which profile: https://opcfoundation-onlineapplications.org/profilereporting/
Actually, I see that the page on the previous link has reference to this tool too (interactive profile viewer).